# How to have more than 28 characters on Gitlab files names listed?

Tags: gitlab

When I come upon my project under *Gitlab*, it opens on a list of files.

Its default display isn't convenient:

- 28 characters per file name,
- leaving two large emergency lanes of white pixels.

Is there a way to set the *Gitlab* display template, so that it isn't set for a 1024 x 768 pixels screen or Smartphone display?

Because, at the moment, all the files of my project look having quite the same name...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to your preferences (`https://gitlab.example.com/-/profile/preferences`) and [set the layout width](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/preferences.html#layout-width). Set it to 'Fluid' so it's not set to a specific width.

If you're self-hosting GitLab and you want a different fixed layout size, then you could modify the CSS file: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/framework/variables.scss#L466-468

However, the changes will be wiped whenever you upgrade your GitLab.

Comment: That's far better with Fluid ! Thanks